# django: classe importada não está sendo chamada

Tags: python, django

Olá, pessoal, fiz a criação de uma `view` pra retornar uma `HttpResponse` simples importando uma classe da pasta models da seguinte forma:

```
from .models import Album
```

e então criando a funçao da view:

```
def index(request):
   all_albums = Album.objects.all()
   html = ''
   for Album in all_albums:
       url = '/music/' + str(album.id) + '/'
       html += '<a href="' + url + '">' + album.album_title + '</a><br>'

   return HttpResponse(html)
```

porém em diversos pontos do meu código, especificadamente aonde tem a classe 'album' está retornando `unresolved reference 'album'` e também a classe Album que foi importada não está sendo usada. Entretanto, tanto o nome da classe e a chamada do import estão corretas até aonde olhei. Alguma solução ou erro que tenham visto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na declaração do loop você está atribuindo à própria classe `Album` em vez da variável `album`.

Substitua esta linha:

```
for Album in all_albums:
```

Por isto:

```
for album in all_albums:
```

Comment: Valeu! Resolveu